# Chime SDK not available in some regions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk

I'm developing an integration between [Aws Chime SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/chime/chime-sdk/) and a Ruby on Rails web application, using the official [aws ruby client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/ChimeSDKMeetings/Client.html). First of all, I try to create a `Aws::ChimeSDKMeetings::Client` passing my credentials and a valid aws region like "eu-south-1" to the constructor. However when I try to call a method like `create_meeting` on the created object, the method fails with `Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (Failed to open TCP connection to meetings-chime.eu-south-1.amazonaws.com:443 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known))`, even if the region I provided is listed as an [available media region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime-sdk/latest/dg/sdk-available-regions.html). If I try to change the region with which I create the client object to "us-east-1", it works properly. I made some attempts and I found that the client works only if it is created within "us-east-1" or "us-west-2" as ragion.

Can someone tell me why it doesn't work with other regions? As long as I searched, I found nothing about it in the official Aws documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few points to mention here while working with AWS Chime SDK:

- Region that you provide to ChimeSDKMeetings client is the control region, underlying AWS SDK is going to call to. There are 4 control regions that you can provide to Client: `us-east-1`, `us-west-2`, `eu-central-1` and `ap-southeast-1`.
- MediaRegion is provided to CreateMeeting command, that can be any of the regions that are listed in the documentation.
- `eu-south-1` region may not be enabled in your account. Go to Account and check AWS Regions section to check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! ‘eu-south-1’ is enabled for my account. I supposed it was a matter of availability of the control region, but I wasn’t able to find a list of the available control regions, so I though they where the same as the media regions.